# How to display application normally

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, process

I am creating a complex service **on Windows 7**, which starts off by loading an .exe application. The only way to achieve this was to enable to "Interactive Services Detection" service in services.msc.

As a test application, I added the following code which simply opens the system calculator. It works, however not as intended. I first get the following message when starting the service:

[image]

When clicking "View this message", it loads the calculator as it is supposed to, but opens a blue full screen mode, and contains the calculator within it.

My question is basically the following: How can I make the application display automatically, and not have to prompt the user to "view the message", and more importantly, how can I get the application to display normally, rather than in this "interactive services detection" sandbox?

This is the code of my sample service:

```
public partial class OpenCalculator : ServiceBase
    {
        public Process process;

        public OpenCalculator()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "Open Calculator";
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            start_calc();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

        protected void start_calc()
        {
            try
            {
                process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe";
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();

                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\Users\\scaruana\\Desktop\\test.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(process);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\Users\\scaruana\\Desktop\\test.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been the cause of great frustration, and I have finally solved my problem. Yes, I have managed to make a service load a GUI application, even though everyone says that it is impossible. There is a warning though - the "fix" can be considered as exploiting a loophole in Windows, as the code which I used basically passes the Vista and Windows 7 UAC. Essentially, the application is always executed with full rights and bypasses the UAC.

If anyone has this same problem, what you need to do is iterate through a list of logged in users on the PC, and choose to open the UI application in this session (which has the user's desktop), rather than in session 0 where the service is supposed to be running (and which does not have a desktop).

For some people, this might not be a solution as it is not secure. But in my case, security is not a main concern, and I just needed it to work (had to be a service by force).

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem that I had.

Comment: Of course I appreciate, however it did not solve my problem, whereas the approach which I took did. So if anyone has the same problem in the future, the above should solve it in an easier manner when compared to bringing WCF and interoperability into play.

Comment: You apparently don't appreciate it. Read my third paragraph again. That's what you did. You seem to be confused between the answer to the question you asked, and the specific solution to your problem that you implemented. I am disappointed.

Comment: You are right about the third paragraph, however that is not what I did exactly. My approach is much simpler and does not involve the type of low-level programming suggested in the article which you linked. I admit I missed that part as I focussed more on your last paragraph where you mentioned IPC :) 

I've +1'd your answer, as that article is one valid way to go about it, although may require higher expertise to achieve.

Comment: You are doing what that article suggests. You are creating a process on a specified desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Services run in session 0, whose desktop you cannot see. Interactive desktops are hosted in other sessions. So, for instance, the first interactive logon runs in session 1. This means that services cannot directly show UI on an interactive desktop.

In older versions of Windows (XP and earlier), the first interactive logon shared session 0 with services. And so when you enabled the *allow service to interact with desktop* option in the service control manager, the service could show UI on an interactive desktop. However, all that ended with Vista because it was a security risk.

So, you need to start a new process and specifically force it onto the desktop of an logged in interactive user. That is not easy to do. This MSDN blog article covers your options: [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx).

Now, that's how you go about starting a new process from a service, and putting the new process onto an interactive desktop. But that is almost certainly the wrong way to solve your problem. As you can see by reading the linked article, doing it that way is complex. The standard solution to your problem is to run an interactive process on the logged in user's desktop. This remains hidden until your service needs to show UI. The service then communicates with the desktop app using your preferred IPC mechanism, and then the desktop app shows the UI.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on the last part please?

Comment: Create a separate desktop app for your UI. Run it, say, at login time with `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Make it hide away in the background. When your service needs to show UI, let it contact the desktop app using IPC and instruct the desktop app to do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: By the way, I've looked at all your recent questions, and they all boil down to the issue covered in this answer.

Comment: I'm going to give your suggestion a shot. Could you provide some information regarding the IPC between the service and UI application? So far, every attempt I have made when using services to try calling batch files, or opening processes, they have been unsuccessful.

Comment: In .net you might choose WCF

Comment: How would WCF work in this case? Would it be used solely for the IPC, or for the services too?

Comment: So to confirm: I would have a GUI application running in the background, which would act as the "server" and the service which communicates with the server, which would be the "client". And all interaction would be carried out through WCF, between the client and server. Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes, that is accurate